# Cypress env variable is undefined when it's called in different method

Tags: cypress

In first method below I set env. variable, but when it's necessary to get this variable in another method, executed under the same test run, it's returned as undefined. What can be the cause of such behavior?

```js
setEnvVar = () => {
    cy.get('tbody > tr').first().find('span').first().then(($span) => {
        Cypress.env('est-id', $span.text())
    })
}
```

```js
fillParameters = () => {    
    cy.get('div[id=estimates_select]').find('input').type(Cypress.env('est-id'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR

Put the `fillParameters()` code inside a `cy.then()`.

```js
fillParameters = () => {
  cy.then(() => {
    cy.get('div[id=estimates_select]')
      .find('input')
      .type(Cypress.env('est-id'))
  })
}
```

---

#### Explanation

All Cypress commands run on a queue. When the test runner runs a test, the parameters for commands like `.type()` and `.log()` are set ***before*** the command queue starts running.

In your code, that means `.type(Cypress.env('est-id'))` evaluates `env('est-id')` before it is set in the preceding function `setEnvVar()`.

The exception is commands added inside a callback such as

```js
cy.then(() => {
  // commands added here defer parameter setting 
  // until this callback is executed in the queue
})
```

---

Using `Cypress.env()` to save values is a **hack** (IMO)

The `.env()` was designed to set values ***outside of the test*** (why it's called environment)

It's often used as a data store, but closure variables or aliases are better in the situation you describe.

Examples:

**Closure variable**

```js
let est-id;

setEnvVar = () => {
  cy.get('tbody > tr').first().find('span').first()
    .then(($span) => est-id = $span.text() )
}

fillParameters = () => {
  cy.get('div[id=estimates_select]').find('input')
    .type(est-id)
}
```

**Alias**

```js
setEnvVar = () => {
  cy.get('tbody > tr').first().find('span').first()
    .invoke('text').as('est-id')
}

fillParameters = () => {
  cy.get('@est-id').then(est-id => {
    cy.get('div[id=estimates_select]').find('input').type(est-id)
  })
}
```